# Lambda Function can be used in this case, or just a def function?

Tags: string, lambda, numbers, max, default

In a statement defined as:

```
def max_value(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)
    value = number1
    if number1 <= number2:
         value = number2
    if number2 <= number3:
         value = number3
    if number3 <= number4:
         value = number4
    if number4 <= number5:
         value = number5
    return value
```

What would be the correct function for using lambda?

```
max_value_lambda = lambda ???????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
max_value_lambda = lambda number1, number2, number3, number4, number5: max(
    number1, number2, number3, number4, number5
)

print(max_value_lambda(1, 6, 4, 3, 2))
```

Prints:

```
6
```

---

Or for arbitrary number of arguments:

```py
max_value_lambda = lambda *args: max(args)

print(max_value_lambda(1, 6, 4, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to create a list with all the numbers and then apply lambda function?

Something like:

```
list = [number1, number2, number3]
max_lambda = lambda x: max(x)
print(max_lambda(list))
```